# React Js gives error on setState call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been playing around with an error which I am not able to understand. Here is the code i am using for rendering a page.

```
export class ResourceEdit extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  this.state = {"resource" : ""}
  }

  getInitialState() {
    return {successVisible: false};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log("ResourceEdit: componentDidUpdate", prevProps.params.id, this.props.params.id);
    if (this.props.params.id != prevProps.params.id) {
      this.loadData();
    }
  }

  loadData() {
    $.ajax('/api/resources/' + this.props.params.id) .done(function(resource) {
      this.setState(resource);
    }.bind(this));

  }

  onChangeCategory(e) {
    this.setState({category: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeSubcategory(e) {
    this.setState({subcategory: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeProduct(e) {
    this.setState({product: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeSolution(e) {
    this.setState({solution: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeWeight(e) {
    this.setState({weight: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeNSOC(e) {
    this.setState({nsoc: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeStatus(e) {
    this.setState({status: e.target.value});
  }

  onChangeDateproductadded(e) {
    this.setState({date_product_added: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeDesignstatus(e) {
    this.setState({design_status: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeDesigncombined(e) {
    this.setState({design_combined: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeImplementstatus(e) {
    this.setState({implement_status: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeImplementcombined(e) {
    this.setState({implement_combined: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeOperatestatus(e) {
    this.setState({operate_status: e.target.value});
  }
  onChangeOperatecombined(e) {
    this.setState({operate_combined: e.target.value});
  }
  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var resource = {
      subcategory: this.state.subcategory,
      category: this.state.category,
      product: this.state.product,
      solution: this.state.solution,
      weight: this.state.weight,
      nsoc: this.state.nsoc,
      status: this.state.status,
      date_product_added: this.state.date_product_added,
      design_status: this.state.design_status,
      design_combined: this.state.design_combined,
      implement_status: this.state.implement_status,
      implement_combined: this.state.implement_combined,
      operate_status: this.state.operate_status,
      operate_combined: this.state.operate_combined
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/resources/' + this.props.params.id, type: 'POST', contentType:'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(resource),
      dataType: 'json',
      success(resource) {
        this.setState(resource);
        this.showSuccess();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    var success = (
      <Alert bsStyle="success" onDismiss={this.dismissSuccess} dismissAfter={5000}>
        Resource saved to DB successfully.
      </Alert>
    );

    return (
      <div style={{maxWidth: 600}}>
        <Panel header={"Edit resource: " + this.props.params.id}>
          <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
            <Input type="text" label="Category" value={this.state.category} onChange={this.onChangeCategory}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Sub Category" value={this.state.subcategory} onChange={this.onChangeSubcategory}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Product" value={this.state.product} onChange={this.onChangeProduct}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Solution" value={this.state.solution} onChange={this.onChangeSolution}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Weight" value={this.state.weight} onChange={this.onChangeWeight}/>
            <Input type="text" label="NSOC" value={this.state.nsoc} onChange={this.onChangeNSOC}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Status" value={this.state.status} onChange={this.onChangeStatus}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Date" value={this.state.date_product_added} onChange={this.onChangeDateproductadded}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Design Status" value={this.state.design_status} onChange={this.onChangeDesignstatus}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Design Players" value={this.state.design_combined} onChange={this.onChangeDesigncombined}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Implement Status" value={this.state.implement_status} onChange={this.onChangeImplementstatus}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Implement Players" value={this.state.implement_combined} onChange={this.onChangeImplementcombined}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Operate Status" value={this.state.operate_status} onChange={this.onChangeOperatestatus}/>
            <Input type="text" label="Operate Players" value={this.state.operate_combined} onChange={this.onChangeOperatecombined}/>
          <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">Submit</Button>
              <Link className="btn btn-link" to="/home">Back</Link>
            </ButtonToolbar>
          </form>
        </Panel>
        {this.state.successVisible ? success : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting an error on page load which says 
Uncaught Error: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.
    at invariant (eval at

Please someone help me figure out what is wrong in this code. Thanks in advance..

Comment: *at ...* ??????

Comment: Clearly in one of the places you call `setState` you're not passing in *"an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables"*. So...debug and find out why not. Debugging is a fundamental, beginning skill, not an advanced one. It's one of the first things to learn.

Comment: What is return in ajax response ? json ? please edit question & add  response of api

Comment: Also note that `this` in the second of your `ajax` callbacks (in `submit`) is not a reference to your component. More [*How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) (It is in your first because you used `bind`. I would use arrow functions instead.)

Comment: inside the done method of ajax, change `this.setState(resource)` to `this.setState({resource})`

Comment: @NagarajTantri: Quite possibly. We can't know, because we don't know what `resource` is, and whether it's meant to be used directly as `state.resource`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thats why the comment, don't know his ajax return value ;)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you call `this.setState()` in a function, make sure to bind it with `this`. In this example,  you might need to bind all of the `onChange` functions with `this`.

You can bind them in the `constructor` then you don't need to worry about it or bind it in the render function.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {"resource" : ""}      

  this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)
  this.onChangeCategory = this.onChangeCategory.bind(this)
  this.onChangeSubcategory = this.onChangeSubcategory.bind(this)
  // and more methods to bind...
}
```

With this kind of practice you don't need to `bind(this)` in the ajax call which can make the code clean and neat.

Hope this helps!